# itext add text to a page result in present but invisible text - font missing?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add a custom text on a pdf with the following code.

It works fine on most of the case, however for some pdfs (mainly scanned images), the text appears as "invisible" : I can select and copy the text, but it's like it has an opacity=0.

```
        PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(is);
        final PdfStamper stamper = PdfAStamper.createSignature(pdfTemplate, os, '\0');
        PdfContentByte content = stamper.getUnderContent(pageNumber);
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(content);
        ct.setSimpleColumn(llx, lly, urx, uly, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        Font headerFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURRIER, 7, Font.NORMAL);
        headerFont.setColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk c = new Chunk("hello", headerFont);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(c);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        ct.addElement(p);
        ct.go();
```

I'm wondering if the pdf is missing the font. Running `pdffont "mypdf.pdf"` returns an error :

```
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Adding `pdfTemplate.createFakeFontSubsets()` in my code result in the following :

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Roman                          Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      1  0
```

I guess the font isn't embedded, but the following doesn't work either :

```
BaseFont courrier = BaseFont.createFont("courrier", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font headerFont = new Font(courrier, 7, Font.NORMAL);
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening, and how can I fix my code to make it works for all kinds of pdf, including scanned pdf ?

(Unfortunately it's a bit complicated for me to give you a pdf example, since it happens on client documents...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
PdfContentByte content = stamper.getUnderContent(pageNumber);
```

You are adding the text *under* the existing content. As the existing content consists of an opaque image, the text is present, but covered by white pixels.

Change the line into:

```
PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent(pageNumber);
```

and your problem will be solved.

You may want to make the text slightly transparent if you don't want to cover the existing content completely.

Comment: Sometimes I feel stupid... as I was able to select the text so I discarded this idea and was focused on the fonts which I guess is stupid since courrier is available by default for Linux/windows.. thanks for the transparent tip